# I have the line in my run.sh : svm-train -and I'm getting the error svm-train: not found. Why is that?

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, svm, libsvm

I have the following line in my run.sh :

```
svm-train -s 0 -c 5 -t 2 -g 0.5 -e 0.1 $file >>logfile
```

and I'm getting the following:

```
error run.sh: 10: run.sh: svm-train: not found
```

I have installed *libsvm* as follows :

1. Downloaded the zip file
2. $ cd libsvm-3.0
      $ make
3. $ cd python/
      $ make
4. import svm

Why am I getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe svm-train is not on your $PATH. One way of checking if svm-train is on your $PATH or not is by typing the following on the command line:

```
echo $PATH | grep svm-train
```

If this doesn't display any output and returns directly to the command prompt, this means that svm-train is really not on your $PATH.

To add svm-train to your path, type the following on the command line:
1. [Optional but recommended] Back up the contents of your original $PATH first:

```
echo $PATH > path.txt
```

If you open path.txt, you can see that the current value of your $PATH environment variable has been written on this file. Let's designate this as "/original/path".

The reason why you might want to perform this step is that in case you want to revert to your original $PATH, you can just copy the contents of path.txt and type:

```
export $PATH=/original/path
```

2. Determine the full path (or full location) of svm-train is stored on your computer. Let's say this location is "/full/path/to/svm-train" as an example.
3. Finally, add the location to your $PATH environment variable by typing:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/full/path/to/svm-train
```

Comment: You are on the right track but this is really not correct.

Comment: Hey, I tried this but it doesn't work. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: :) btw, in case you find the answer, please post it so that others will also know :)